# how to apply motion to a model in blender

Tags: python-3.x, kinect-sdk, blender-2.61

I am doing one experiment in which I need to capture skeleton data from kinect and then apply that data to a model, I have captured data from kinect and have stored it in a file, i.e  in a file i have location of each joint in each frame,
Now I want my model in blender to take the joint position from file, and move accordingly. But I dont have any idea on how to start.
I also have written a small script in python to read position from file and update the position of one bone:

```
    obj.channels['head'].location = Vector((float(xs),float(ys),float(zs)))
```

but it does not move anything. Am I doing it in wrong way, or we cannot move the armature by just updating the position??

Please guide me on this topic, as i am completely new to python and blender

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is the best solution, you can simply export your data to a bvh file and save yourself from a lot of headaches.

You can find a lot of [Kinect-sdk to bvh](http://www.google.com/#q=kinect+sdk+to+bvh) tutorials on the net and the bvh is the de-facto standard to store data from motion capture events, there are no reasons why you should re-invent the wheel and doing extra work.

To use your bvh file in Blender you can simply follow [one of the many tutorial](http://www.3dartistonline.com/news/2011/03/free-blender-tutorial/) on the subject.

Comment: I have tried converting Kinect-sdk data to bvh format, but could not succeed

Comment: @user2190460 and then dealing with matrices and linear algebra it's not gonna be easier for you, there are tutorials for the bvh, find one that is good for you, this is a really simple solution compared to what you are trying to achieve with just python 3 and Blender APIs